Is Buhler's "asymmetrical electrostatic differential propulsion" real and propellantless?
Recently I have read about Exodus Propulsion's apparent breakthrough in the realm of electric propulsion, with a new form of propulsion being the so-called "asymmetrical electrostatic differential" propulsion. According to Dr. Buhler based on articles describing interviews with him and also video interviews on YouTube, he has figured out a way to use some sort of electrostatic configuration to generate significant forces (including forces apparently up to over one Earth gravity of acceleration on a lightweight craft).
Buhler himself actually has worked with NASA quite a bit, including electrostatic discharge (ESD) safety for the Space Shuttle and ISS programs, as well as on the Hubble Space Telescope. I would consider this reliable, but his propulsion system is propellantless and obviously violates thermodynamics - it generates infinite kinetic energy from an electrostatic field. All one would require is a system that keeps those electrostatic charges in place (which, given that it's electrostatic i.e. unchanging electric fields over time, should be trivial), and his device would produce infinite force from zero energy input.
There have been an increasingly-large number of articles documenting his work, and although he does seem credible enough, the media has also been known to document things that are less-than-true (see the NASA asteroid impact defense scenario debacle that happened a while back, where NASA hosted a training scenario to see if they could prepare for a 14-year-out asteroid impact to save humanity and the media interpreted it as there actually being a 14-year-out asteroid bound to hit Earth). Is anything he's saying legit/backed by NASA/other credible sources, or is he the next Norman Dean?
My research points to two main sources: physics forums talking about how his concept is absolutely absurd and doesn't make any sense, and then Buhler and the media talking about how his lab (without further specification) is able to detect >1-g acceleration from his device. The scientists are asking for an in-space test, while Buhler himself seems happy with his results on the ground; this is already somewhat unscientific, but I wonder if there's any secondary evidence/actual reports or schematics/raw lab data or personnel lists that might further corroborate Buhler's claims, or if no such information can be found, if he's just thinking he found something out that he didn't.

For the record: I would 100% believe that he's figured out how to use the Earth's electromagnetic field to his advantage - if you could get a craft light enough and responsive enough to the Earth's own EM field, I believe you could make it appear to fly around without propellant (the propellant sort of being the Earth itself). But from what I've read he's claiming that it would also work in the absence of external EM fields, which  doesn't make any sense, since that would violate the most basic principles of physics.

The article links International Patent WO2020159603A2, which probably has a better technical description of the device.

The claim of a huge space propulsion breakthrough seems a bit premature if Buhler won't take it into space. And the story says "The strongest force they generated is 10 millinewtons. IF they can setup the experiment correctly they could levitate a 1 gram test article". And it seems to require a voltage input, cough. The patent apparently refers to "The device is described as a system and method for generating a force from a voltage difference applied across at least one electrically conductive surface." If so, it ain't owt for nowt.

I would like to see this question edited so there is less of the OP's opinions about what might be happening, and more direct quotes of the claim.

I'm also not sure what we are going to be able to add. It seems you already know the scientific consensus seems to be the claim is impossible due to Newton's Laws, and a real test (in space) has yet to be performed. Seems like a claim that the skeptics community would provisionally reject until further evidence is produced. What more could we add until then?

"Is it propellantless?" presumably refers to conventional liquid propellants. Perhaps Dr. Buhler has nuclear power in mind for his propulsion effect, but there have already been tests of an ion thruster/engine conducted by NASA. I wonder if Buhler worked on that program, having "worked with NASA".

Smells like the debunked "propellant-less" EM Drive. Testing forces that fleeting means any tiny flaw in the apparatus can produce the observed force. Like the EM Drive, it will probably take years of careful testing to truly determine if there's something to it.

This question has alot opinions and has really no evidence mentioned. I'm bookmarking this for later.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This could easily be tested by measuring the current.  Likely any working demonstration takes enough current that, multiplied by the high voltage, it will produce enough power to generate the lift.  Most likely is that it works by using electrons as reaction mass--generate a negative voltage, create a positive terminal that's hollow or somehow manages to let a large percentage of them pass, much like the grid of a vacuum tube.  Of course, around here we're surrounded by matter full of electrons to refill the apparatus, but running out of electrons might be a more significant issue in space.

"would produce infinite force from zero energy input." - is that your conclusion, or a direct quote? From whom?

After JiminyCricket, WeatherVane, et al, can you first define 'propellantless'? My assumption is that should mean something like 'without fuel' but can you confirm that's what it means here, and not for instance 'without source of propulsion'?
